# JSPlumb - Change ID or UUID of an Endpoint

Tags: jsplumb

How can I change the ID (or at least the UUID) of an existing endpoint in jsPlumb?

I am creating endpoints using the following code and when the element they are associated with has an ID change, I want to also update the endpoints. I am using some patterns on the endpoints + connections in a higher-level model so I need to keep these in sync. I could capture the jsplumb id in my own model but I would rather not pollute my model with details of JSPlumb. My model id properties are tied to jsplumb uuid properties.

```
var inEndpointUuid = "Endpoint_Target_" + $(element).attr('id');
var inEndpointOption = {
    isSource: false,
    isTarget: true,
    uuid: inEndpointUuid
};
var inEndpoint = jsPlumbInstance.addEndpoint(element, inEndpointOption);
```

Later, then I need to change the id of the element, I would also like to change the Id/UUID of any endpoints on it. Bonus, I also need to change this on any affected connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `setEndpointUuid` method on the jsPlumbInstance class. It changes the endpoint's uuid property and updates the internal map.

https://github.com/jsplumb/community-edition/blob/master/ts/core/core.ts#L1336C5-L1347C6